# audience grows larger and less <finessed> = subtle?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*How I escaped my certain fate by Stewart Lee*

> On a good day, this is the difference between Ricky Gervais and Jim
>   Davidson, a difference Davidson fails to grasp and one which, to be
>   fair, becomes increasingly irrelevant to Gervais’s audience too as it
>   grows larger and less **finessed**

Stewart Lee describes different styles of these two comedians: Ricky Gervais and Jim Davidson.
Does he mean that the audience of Ricky Gervais grows larger and it's less **subtle**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know but that word looks out of place to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this context it means "less refined", implying that as Ricky Gervais's audience grows larger, it attracts people who may lack the *finesse* (= sophistication) to really appreciate the aspects of his comedic style that set him apart from Jim Davidson.

Comment: I guess that's broadly along the lines of the answers you got here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/audience-grows-larger-and-less-finessed-controlled.3693416/